# upload file to s3 and make it public and get url

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to upload the image to s3  and make them public so that user can download them by there links. I want to write python code for that.

I am using boto3.

```
for i in ans:
    count+=1
    img_name=code+"_img"+str(count)+".jpg"
    f=open(img_name,"w")
    ans[i].save(f)
    f.close()
    s3.upload_file(Bucket = 'bucket',Filename="./"+img_name,Key=img_name)
    object_acl = s3.ObjectAcl('bucket',img_name)
    response = object_acl.put(ACL='public-read')
    print(res)
    time.sleep(2)
    key = bucket.lookup(img_name)
    key.set_acl('public-read')
```

Comment: You should explain where you are facing error, and include the description of error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would assist us if you could please edit your question to provide more details. For example, is your code currently working? What difficulty are you facing? Do you receive an error message? Also, please include your actual question.